# Why didn't Pietro Maximoff tell Magneto they were related?

Tags: x-men-cinematic-universe, x-men-apocalypse

In *X-Men: Apocalypse* we get confirmation from Pietro that Magneto is his father, and he (Pietro) knows it. However, he never mentions this fact to Magneto. Wouldn't this be something he would want to do when the two of them were together?

Is there a reason given in the movie why Pietro wouldn't bring this up at any point?

Comment: Thanks to the person who helped edited my question. I wish to add : it's pietro maximoff(quicksilver) , not maxomoff. Also, some comic book or Wikipedia readers will know that pietro is magneto's son.

Comment: and some comic book readers also know that [magneto is not actually his father.](http://www.newsarama.com/22948-did-marvel-comics-just-solve-the-mcu-s-scarlet-witch-quicksilver-father-problem-spoilers.html)

Comment: The obvious, and I believe only, answer is "Because he decided not to." He was about to when Mystique was trying to convince Magneto to help fight against Apocalypse, then doesn't; he says "You're my ... I'm here for my family too." Then at the end he says that he might tell Magneto eventually. Why he decided not to would be pure speculation, it's not mentioned anywhere in the movie.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist Which doesn't mean it's not an excellent possibility for reasonable character analysis based on the movie. Even if Pietro never explicitly says "I don't want to tell him because...", it doesn't mean his character doesn't still offer some reasonable explanations.

Comment: I think he is disappointed by the father he used to idealize

Comment: Maybe they just saved that important scene for another film, since this one was already getting too crowded. Dark Phoenix maybe ...

Answer (score 10):

To directly answer your question...

**No.** There is no reason given in the movie as to why Pietro wouldn't tell Magneto he was his son.

If we were to speculate there could be numerous reasons. My own thought on it is that he didn't want Magneto to stop what he was doing just because his son asked him but rather wanted Magneto to stop because it was the right thing to do.

Answer (score 4):

[Because it's emotionally difficult to deal with his literal daddy issues](https://www.yahoo.com/movies/evan-peters-expands-on-x-men-reveal-that-magneto-213723085.html). From an [interview with Evan Peters](http://moviepilot.com/posts/3907637), the X-Men Quicksilver, on the character motivation:

> Evan Peters didn't say too much about Quicksilver and Magneto's relationship in the movie because he didn't want to give some things away but he did hinted us with a little bit of a drama moment between the two.
>
> > **Evan Peters: It’s tough, man, it’s a hard thing to meet with an estranged father. It’s a very difficult thing. It’s a very real thing.** So it was interesting to play that side of Quicksilver.

Ask anyone who has been adopted and decides to track down their birth parents (or not, an equally difficult decision).

Pietro was also dealing with his own young adult identity crisis.

> Evan Peters: It's a big motivation for Quicksilver to get out of his mom's basement. He's trying to find his father and help him out.

In the film, there is the scene where he relates how Mystique's 1963 saving of President Nixon affected him, talking about he's still a loser living in his mom's basement.

In short, too much emotional turmoil in a difficult situation. Seeing his father, face to face, after realizing he is his father too late last time, he froze up like a deer in headlights, and ran off. A typical fight or flight response for someone still maturing.